# Qt Creator Compiler Config Issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have just started to learn C++ and have come across Qt Creator. I have installed it alongside the built in MinGW Compiler. However I cannot get  my projects to 'Build and Run'. I have attached some screenshots below, thank you for any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last image shows the two auto-detected kits which I can choose from. I tried creating my own kit and linked it with the compiler since the auto-detected kits don't have the compiler linked to it.

Also, the following error shows when I try to 'Build and Run' my project :

`18:02:25: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project Test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 64bit)
When executing step "Make"`

Comment: You need to go back to the kit panel and add the compiler. Also, fwiw, I would drop one of the versions of Qt, having two is asking for trouble.

Comment: @johnelemans I have all the official distributions installed and several homebrewed ones and never knew any troubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dry facts:

- You've installed Qt distributions (libraries, include files, etc.) of versions 5.6 and 5.7 built to use with Visual Studio C++ 2015 compiler.
- You don't have Visual Studio 2015 C++ compiler (or it is not properly set up)
- You've installed MinGW 4.9.2, which is a windows port of GCC compiler.
- You haven't installed Qt for MinGW

Problem:

- Due to a lack of binary compatibility between C++ compilers, Qt distributions (same as any other libraries) built with one compiler cannot be linked with code compiled with another compiler. QtCreator knows this and warns you.

Possible solutions:

- Install Qt for MinGW (with maintenancetool.exe in Qt folder)
- Install [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (make sure you check "C++ tools" during installation)
- Install both
- Install other *matching* pairs of { compiler, Qt_distribution }

  (in last two cases you can easily swap between toolchains)

Make sure you roll back any damage you've made to compiler settings in QtCreator.

See also:
[Installing Qt 5.6: Which components should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106187/installing-qt-5-6-which-components-should-i-choose)

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't see the MinGW module within Qt 5.6 when installing...that did the trick! :)