# Qt Creator Compiler Config Issue visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem very similar to 
[Qt Creator Compiler Config Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685474/qt-creator-compiler-config-issue)

I have a code in one computer that run with qt 5.4.2msvc2013. In this computer everything works fine, I have these packages installed for the kit:
[Build & run kits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Iy4.png)

but now I am trying to run the same program in a new computer and I can not get my projects to 'Build and Run'.

I tried to install visual studio 2017 but it didn't work. I think the problem is that I don't know what do I have to install in the visual studio package to run something with Qt 5.4.2msvc2013 64bit2

Here is what I installed of visual studio 2017 in the computer that doesn't work
[Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdhxp.png)

thank you for any help!

Comment: Qt latest version seems not support VS 2017 yet. I see the most latest qt-vs addin in [Qt Archive](http://download.qt.io/archive/vsaddin/) is VS 2015.

Comment: Many thanks. From the page you gave me, I think qt-vs-tools-msvc2013-2.1.1.vsix will work for me. Do you know what do I need to do after download the file?

Comment: You need to install the qt-vs addin, and then configure Qt settings to include your Qt install directory, Qt project settings to set your Qt version, in Visual Studio.

Comment: I also have the same problem with Qt and VS 2017, but I don't want to reinstall the VS to 2015. Is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

To compile VS2013/Qt5 project under VS2017 you need to install full VS2013 together with VS2017. I tried [MS Build Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) but that's not sufficient because [does not include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721281/installing-platform-toolset-v120-under-visual-studio-2015) unmanadged C++ compiler (cl.exe). Also, you need proper version of Qt itself and Qt VS Tools (aka Qt VS Addin). At the moment beta with VS2017 support is [available](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/).